# Flutter_ffmpeg: how to get video and audio from url or storage

Tags: flutter, audio, video, ffmpeg, merge

Actually i am very confused how i can give video and audio file to Flutter ffmpeg by url or by storage.so it can can give me the output by margarine it.i don't no how ffmpeg work in flutter .i used path provider to give the video and audio file to ffmpeg but i did't get any documentation showing how to provide video or audio file to ffmpeg. so please any can tell me how i can provide file to ffmpeg,it will be big help to me Thank You.

i tryed to add some code from Flutter ffmpeg documentation what ever i do i always get some unknown errors.

```dart
final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
  
var arguments = ["-i", "file1.mp4", "-c:a", "mpeg4", "file2.mp3"];
  
VideoAudio.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Comment: You mention the path provider. What path did it give you for the incoming **mp4** file?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Server Url**

```
    final FlutterFFprobe _flutterFFprobe = new FlutterFFprobe();
    _flutterFFprobe
        .execute("-print_format json -show_chapters  \ ${'url'}") //server url
        .then((rc) => print(rc));
    final FlutterFFmpegConfig _flutterFFmpegConfig = new FlutterFFmpegConfig();
    _flutterFFmpegConfig.enableLogCallback(this.logCallback);

void logCallback(int level, String message) {
 // Response of FFMPEG 
}
```

**2. Local Storage**

```
  File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/OTT/out.mp4'); // local stoage 
    final FlutterFFmpegConfig _flutterFFmpegConfig = new FlutterFFmpegConfig();
    _flutterFFprobe
        .execute("-print_format json -show_chapters  \ ${file.path}")
        .then((rc) => print(rc));

    _flutterFFmpegConfig.enableLogCallback(this.logCallback); 


void logCallback(int level, String message) {
 // Response of FFMPEG 
}
```